# Deleting "or" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, ellipses

> He plays it good, (or) at least better than you.

Can I omit word "or" in this sentence like this?

> He plays it good, at least better than you.

The reason I am asking it is because of this type of sentences.

> He is tall, maybe taller than you.
>
> He weighs a lot, perhaps 270kg.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can omit "or," but the sentence works much better with "or."

Also note that "good" doesn't work in this sentence because you need an adverb, to modify the verb *plays*.

> He plays it well, or at least better than you.

Comment: Thanks! And also, can you explain why it is possible to omit or?